# Black Space show in MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, iphone

[image: SideMenu Screen Shot]

I have used MFSideMenu in objectiveC. But when the sideMenu appear the black background show on top.
I have use all (header and footer of tableview). Also hide the Navigation Bar.But problem is not solve.
Can Anybody help me.

Comment: Post screenshot

Comment: I have post ScreenShot after edit my question, please find the attachment..

Comment: If you are using a view controller side menu then please  add tableview.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets  = no

Comment: Actually we have use SideMenu when we will completer the Registration in this app. It means we will use sideMenu after some ViewController.(Side Menu will appear on click of menu button in MyDashboard ViewController)

Comment: i know there must a view controller or reference to provide value for tableview .So in that tableview.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = no

Comment: I have used, but it is not work.

Comment: Show how you added it as a conainer . and where you are adding tableview.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = no

Comment: I have added in SideMenuViewController.m 

firstly i used tableview.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = no (But it have error)  
So i have used self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: anybody help me, i already try after removing tableview and add new tableview but the problem is not solved.